# How to show the module name after imported maven project in idea?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, import, module

I imported a maven project as a module in idea 13, but after that in the project navigation on the left showed the directory name of my maven project, not the module name. I want the navigation shows the module name, how can i do that?

Comment: I'm so sorry that i don't have enough reputation to upload image. The absolute path of my project like "d:\\workspace\branch\02", after i imported the project to idea as a module, the idea showed the module like this, "02[tj-v3]". The "tj-v3" was the module name i inputed.

Comment: You can post the code in the question using code block